# Modded Minecraft with Forge won't launch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

In all versions of Minecraft with Forge (I tried with 1.7.10, 1.7.2 and 1.6.4) I am perfectly capable of launching Vanilla Minecraft from the launcher, when I attempt to launch it with Forge, the process simply stops, no crash, or anything of the sort. The launcher closes itself, there is no error message, it simply stops the process. The launcher doesn't reopen. How do I get it to run properly?

Comment: You can find your error logs in %AppData%/Roaming/.minecraft/logs/... Also, you may want to take a look at this http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9943/how-do-i-ask-a-good-minecraft-bug-crash-question and edit your question to fit it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is tech support for modded Minecraft. We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft

Answer (score 2):

Down/upgrade your java to 1.7. Forge doesn't seem to support java 1.8 (yet)...

Comment: When installing Java 1.8, it has an option for not uninstalling Java 1.7. If you accidentally did not uncheck this option. You can still download Java manually (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html#jre-7u76-oth-JPR). Unpack the tar.gz and copy the content to fit the path indicated in "minecraftdad" answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a new load of minecraft will still load the 8.1 version of Java it downloads into the 'program files(x86)\minecraft\Java' directory. Forge defaults to this. I had the same problem and deleted and reloaded everything. Same problem. Forge dies after you click "play"

What you need to do is under edit profile. click use other Java settings Advanced and give it the path to the Java 7 bin file. Mine was "c:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe"

Worked first time after that and no problems since.

Comment: Yeah, Minecraft has been having **BIG** issues with Java 8 for quite a while now. Either Java 6 or 7 work great.

Comment: The java 8 installer prompts to uninstall old java versions (like the java 7 you have installed.). Only if you would skip that option in the installer, that would work.